# How do I set a variable that uses another variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set a variable that uses another variable in a bash script:

```
echo "Enter server IP:"
read serverIP

ssh="ssh $serverIP"

$ssh cp ...
$ssh mv ...
$ssh rm ...
```

However, this doesn't work. What is the correct syntax in this case?

Comment: What is the error or behavior? do an echo $ssh.

Comment: It just outputs `ssh`. It doesn't have the IP I entered.

Comment: Your assignment should work fine. It's the execution of the variable as a command that's the problem. Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Why do you need to have the command in a variable?

Comment: Dennis: to repeat it multiple times without having to type it in multiple times (like in the last 3 lines of my code example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
SERVER_IP="127.0.0.1"
alias ssh="ssh $SERVER_IP"
```

and you are good to go

Comment: This doesn't seem to output the IP I entered. If I do an `echo ssh`, only `ssh` is outputted.

Comment: @DanielT. Try `echo $ssh` with a `$`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run [remote commands via SSH](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/096), the only safe way is to use [arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) and parameter escaping.

First, use one array to store the command, options, flags, parameters etc. For example:

```
remote_cmd=(touch -- "path with spaces")
echo "${remote_cmd[2]}" # path with spaces
```

You'll need to escape each of these arguments for running via SSH:

```
for arg in "${remote_cmd[@]}"
do
    remote_cmd_escaped+=("$(printf %q "$arg")")
done
echo "${remote_cmd_escaped[2]}" # path\ with\ spaces
```

Then you should use another array for the SSH command itself:

```
ssh_cmd=(ssh "localhost" "${remote_cmd_escaped[@]}")
```

Now you can run it without problems:

```
"${ssh_cmd[@]}"
```

Verify that the file was created with spaces:

```
ls "$HOME/path with spaces"
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 eval $ssh cp ...
```

I don't think setting serverIP and ssh are the problem is referencing the value.

Eval postpones the final submission of the command from the shell to the system, allowing another pass. In the first pass, the `$ssh` is expanded, in the 2nd and final (eval) pass, now the shell can see that $ssh really means `ssh 10.10.10.10` (for example).

Eval is consider evil, it is possible that a user could submit correct sytnax via the serverIP variable that would perform `/bin/rm -rf /*`. So be careful how you use it.

A final bit of trivia, it is possible, but hardly every practical, to use more that 1 eval pass on a line, i.e. `eval eval eval... \$${ssh} ....`.

I hope this helps.